# Get Product attribute to Javascript

Tags: product, attributes, javascript, static-block

I'm making and slide in function to that product page. So when you are close to the bottom a static block will come visible.

That static block should have a link to an article the link is different from product to product and is set in by a custom product attribute.

The problem is to get that custom attribute into my .js can you help?

**What I've done so far**

1. Call in an custom.js in page.xml
2. Make static block, and call it in at the bottom on view.phtml

custom_att name is *article link*
The js have only the "do somthing when you are close to bottom" function right now

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
   if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() > jQuery(document).height() - 100) {
       alert("near bottom!");
   }
})
```

Comment: custom attribute name and add js code too

Comment: Ive added more data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place this JS code anywhere to product page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var article_link = "<?php echo $product->getArticleLink() ?>";
</script>
```

Now you can use `javascript` variable `article_link` anywhere on `.js` file, in your case it's `custom.js`

Comment: Every time i try I destoy all the other js on the site :O

Comment: Can you send VIEW-SOURCE of this line `var article_link = '<?php echo $product->getArticleLink() ?>';`

Comment: What do you need? :D

Comment: Do VIEW-SOURCE of the page (ctrl+U), and send me the above line. O/W send me product page link

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> 
var article_link = <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function getartikelkode() on null in <b>/var/www/ifp.dk/public_html/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml</b> on line <b>534</b><br />

And a random product page is http://ifp.dev.magepartner.net/powerpoint-kursus-den-visuelle-og-effektfulde-praesentation.html

Comment: please replace `$product` with your product instance. I think it is `$_product`

Comment: I cant use the variable in my custom .js i get "undefiend" when i console.log

Comment: `console.log(article_link);` Also note DOUBLE QUOTES of this line `var article_link = "<?php echo $product->getArticleLink() ?>";`

Comment: It was the double quotes that did it! thanks! :D